# React Child with useEffect() not updating on Parent State Change

Tags: reactjs

In my parent Component:

```
<div>
  <h3>Option <span>{this.state.currentOption + 1}</span> of <span>{this.state.options}</span></h3>
  <Button onClick={this.handleOption} variant="primary" type="submit">
    {` Next >>`}
  </Button>
</div>
```

I am calling a hook:

```
handleOption = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let option = this.state.currentOption;
  const numOptions = this.state.stackOptions.length;
  if (++option >= numOptions) {
    option = 0;
  } 
  this.setState({
    currentOption: option,
  });
}
```

Which I wish to cycle through an array of objects to render in Canvas:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

const StackRender = props => {
  
  const canvasRef = useRef(null)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    renderOption(props.name, canvas)
  }, [])
  
  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...props}/>
}
```

however, the child component (the canvas) doesn't update on the parent state change.

Comment: @gavgrif yeah, an edit problem, I dropped a curly brace.  I updated above

Comment: Your `useEffect` has an empty dependency array. This means that it will run only once, when the component originally renders and never again. You mention that you're calling a 'hook' (which is actually just a function, not a hook) which you want to cause a rerender in `StackRender` but I'm not sure how the two components are associated. Are you expecting this because `props.name` changes? Is this based off of `option` in state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `props.name` to the `useEffect` dependency array so the function is called whenever `props.name` changes:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    renderOption(props.name, canvas)
  }, [props.name])
```

Comment: What if I don’t know any keys of the array?